# How to find the count of an element in a matrix without brute force? Can we do that?

Tags: c++

I want to check whether an element is present in the given array(2D) and to find the count towards the left of a cell and to the right of a cell and also to the top and bottom.How can i do it without using brute force

Comment: I think u have no choice. U have to traverse across element anyway

Comment: I'm pretty sure that unless you know something about the 2D array that I don't know, you have to walk through it. There may be functions like `vectro::find` that does the walk for you, but it's still "look at each element". Of course, if it's sorted, or you know that elements are only in certain places for certain values, you could use that to your advantage.

Comment: What do you know about this Matrix? Is it sorted? Is it diagonal? Is it sparse? Knowing these kinds of things help you reduce the search space considerably.

Comment: How many such queries are you expected to perform? Are there any limitations on the range of values that will be present in the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is sorted then you can find in O(nlogm) time complexity using binary search!
where n,m is the rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers (probably not very useful for any present applications, just an idea for thought) is Grover's algorithm.  A exert from Wikipedia:

> Grover's algorithm is a quantum algorithm for searching an unsorted
>   database with N entries in O(N1/2) time and using O(log N) storage
>   space (see big O notation). Lov Grover formulated it in 1996.
>
> In models of classical computation, searching an unsorted database
>   cannot be done in less than linear time (so merely searching through
>   every item is optimal). Grover's algorithm illustrates that in the
>   quantum model searching can be done faster than this; in fact its time
>   complexity O(N1/2) is asymptotically the fastest possible for
>   searching an unsorted database in the linear quantum model.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is unsorted, and you don't have anything like hash-tables for quick access, there is no way.

If your matrix is, for example, sorted, you can use more effective search algorithms (such as binary search, for example) to find the element faster. Don't forget that a 2D array can be represented with a vector, and a variable to hold the column count.